# Textview properties in ListView do not change

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, textview

I have a `ListView`, but when I try to change the text color and size of the `TextView` in the `ListView`, it doesn't change, but I don't get an error. I used to get errors when I tried something but now I don't. I do not know how to do it. Here is the image showing the `ListView`:

[image: ListView]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    List<pdfClass> uploads;
    ListView listview;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = findViewById(R.id.listview);
        floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        uploads = new ArrayList<>();

        viewAllFiles();

        listview.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
            pdfClass pdfupload = uploads.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(pdfupload.getUrl()));
            startActivity(intent);
        });

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(view->{
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UploadPDF.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        });
    }

    private void viewAllFiles() {

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Uploads");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    pdfClass pdfClass = postsnapshot.getValue(furkan.demirel.myapplication.pdfClass.class);
                    uploads.add(pdfClass);


                }
                String[] Uploads = new String[uploads.size()];
                for (int i =0;i<Uploads.length;i++){
                    Uploads[i]=uploads.get(i).getName();

                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Uploads){


                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
                        View view = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
                        TextView text =(TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        text.setTextSize(22);
                        return view;
                    }
                };
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            }



            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the layout.

Lile this:

Add `custom_textview.xml`

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding=" utf-8 "? >
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/tv"
 android:textColor="@color/black"
 android:textSize="22sp"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Change adapter's item layout.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_textview, yourData);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If still not working, you can try [implement Adapter](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial)

If still not working, think about set adapter early.